# Azure B2B direct federation with Auth0 as IDP

Tags: azure-active-directory

Azure B2B gives simple steps for direct federation with google and facebook.Though, i don't see any documentation to establish direct federation with Auth0 or Okta. I tried myself with Auth0 at the time or invitation my user succesfully login with auth0 account but after redirection to invitation.microsoft.com getting redemtion failure.

Can someone give me steps to setup Auth0 as IDP and then configure that with Azure AD direct federation.
https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml-configuration-options/configure-auth0-as-saml-identity-provider
i have already setup everything as mentioned in above document but still not able to redeem invitation after login.

Any help would be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2B can be configured to federate with identity providers that use the WS-Fed or SAML. There is no specific Document for direct federation either from OKTA or Azure. From Azure end Direct federation is only allowed for policies where the authentication URL’s domain matches the target domain, or where the authentication URL is one of these allowed identity providers as per this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation). I recommend you to open a support case with Auth0 since it involves multiple parties.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create user with email username@auth0tenant. Next try login in private mode from url https://myapps.microsoft.com?tenantid=&login_hint=. It should work. If not please check nameidentifier format and audience is configured as per MS documentation in Auth0 SAML Configuration